# Does packet based logging cause network latency?

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm capturing all the incoming/outgoing packets in my system(Linux). I'm using ulogd tool to do that. All the packets flow through IP table rules, and logging happens. My understanding is that logger takes some time to log the packets, and it becomes part of network latency. Is it correct? ( I did a basic ping test to the localhost with ulogd packet capturing/without ulogd packet capturing, and measured the rtt min/avg/max/mdev. I saw .006 ms difference between test(with ulogd) and test(without ulogd).

Does flow based logging avoids this kind of network latency in general? (Not specific to ulogd tool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no. Mere logging doesn't delay the delivery of the packet as the logging can be completed after the packet has been delivered. Only actions that require making a decision that affects what happens to the packet require a delay in forwarding/routing.

Comment: Thanks. Consider the NFLOG target in IP tables. Man page on iptables says, a rule with NFLOG as a target is a non terminating target, and I have a question here.  A packet that matches this NFLOG target, and will the iptables immediately return to the next rule in the iptables chain, or it will wait for NFLOG to finish its execution?

Comment: It will wait for the NFLOG rule to finish its execution. But that's finished as soon as the dispatch to the virtual device is finished. It doesn't have to wait for the actual logging to take place.

Comment: Thanks again, I understand that iptables will not wait for logging to take place. Have one question what do you mean by 'dispatch to the virtual device'

Comment: The way NFLOG works is that there's a virtual device that links the networking code to the logging code. The rule dispatches information to the virtual device and the logging code picks it up later and logs it. It kind of acts like a mailbox.

Comment: Wow, I'm clear now. Unfortunately I'm not able to find a clear documentation on how NFLOG works. Just got bits and pieces of NFLOG.

Comment: Well, the iptables rule decides which packets are to be logged. Then a program running in user space [accesses the to be logged packets](http://netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_log/index.html) and logs them.

Comment: If I use NFLOG target with polling mode with frequent interval checks, I assume I will have considerable cpu usage, and no network delay. Is it correct?

Comment: I guess it depends on how much stuff you log. But the network delay should be insignificant unless the system gets CPU starved.